# PHP preg_match_all struggling with multiple instances of the same code

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match-all

I am processing bulk data in this format:

```
<div class="game"><img src="image.jpg"></div>
```

I am extracting the image paths.

Here is my regex:

```
\<div class\=\"game\"\>\<img src\=\"(.*)\"\>\<\/div\>
```

Here is my preg_match_all command:

```
preg_match_all("/\<div class\=\\"game\\"\>\<img src\=\\"(.*)\\"\>\<\/div\>/", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

If I try to process a single div/img tag it works, like this:

```
array(2
0   =>  array(1
0   =>  <div class="game"><img src="image.jpg"></div>
)
1   =>  array(1
0   =>  image.jpg
)
)
```

However when I process bulk data it fails, for example when processing this:

```
<div class="game"><img src="image.jpg"></div><div class="game"><img src="image2.jpg"></div><div class="game"><img src="image3.jpg"></div><div class="game"><img src="image4.jpg"></div>
```

The array returned is this:

```
array(2
0   =>  array(1
0   =>  <div class="game"><img src="image.jpg"></div><div class="game">
<img src="image2.jpg"></div><div class="game"><img src="image3.jpg">
</div><div class="game"><img src="image4.jpg"></div>
)
1   =>  array(1
0   =>  image.jpg"></div><div class="game"><img src="image2.jpg"></div>
<div class="game"><img src="image3.jpg"></div><div class="game"><img 
src="image4.jpg
)
)
```

It matches everything between the first

```
<div class="game"><img src="
```

and the last

```
"></div>
```

I kind of understand why it happens but there must be a way of preventing this? I bet it is something simple, I've tried a bunch of things and have been Googling a variety of things... hard to list it all.

Comment: Less greedy `(.*?)`, fewer escaping `\<`. Also wouldn't just extracting be simpler? For less consistent HTML / or if performance not an issue use a simpler DOM traversal frontend.

Comment: Thanks mario, changing all .* to .*? has solved the problem, I knew it would be something simple. I dumbed down the pattern and string for a variety of reasons - to make it easier for people to read it here and help me and to protect some confidential data just some of them but for this particular case regex will work well for me rather than using a DOM parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Brief

As mentioned in the comments, simply changing `.*` to `.*?` will solve your problems. This answer is an alternative to that solution which returns the image source in the full match instead of a capture group. This solution also uses fewer steps to reach the intended result than the `.*?` option and also takes the possibility of whitespace into account.

Also, as a sidenote, you don't need to escape *every* character in regex, only special ones such as `\/[]()?*+.^$`

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/Pg2DvE/1)

```
<div\s+class="game"\s*>\s*<img\s+src="\K[^"]*(?="\s*>\s*</div>)
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
<div class="game"><img src="image.jpg"></div><div class="game">
<img src="image2.jpg"></div><div class="game"><img src="image3.jpg">
</div><div class="game"><img src="image4.jpg"></div>
```

#### Output

```
image.jpg
image2.jpg
image2.jpg
image4.jpg
```

---

### Explanation

- `<div` Match this literally
- `\s+` Match one or more whitespace characters
- `class="game"` Match this literally
- `\s*` Match any number of whitespace characters
- `>` Match this literally
- `\s*` Match any number of whitespace characters
- `<img` Match this literally
- `\s+` Match one or more whitespace characters
- `src="` Match this literally
- `\K` Resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match
- `[^"]*` Match any character not present in the set (any character except `"`)
- `(?="\s*>\s*</div>)` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows matches

  - `"` Match this literally
  - `\s*` Match any number of whitespace characters
  - `>` Match this literally
  - `\s*` Match any number of whitespace characters
  - `</div>` Match this literally

**Note**: The regex is delimited by a character other than `/` (the link uses `@`, which PHP allows to do).

Comment: Thanks, changing all .* to .*? has solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Obligatory "don't use Regex to parse HTML" answer.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($input_lines);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$images = $xpath->query("//div[@class='game']/img");
$sources = [];
foreach($images as $image) {
    $sources[] = $image->getAttribute("src");
}
var_dump($sources);
```

Personally I think it's a lot more immediately obvious what this is doing, even if you don't know XPath syntax.